# Laravel sync localhost MySql database to hosting server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter

I want o make offline online web application with Laravel. When users have internet connection so it need to be auto sync MySql database or i will make a button for sync . I tried for solutions but unfortunately i didn't find any solution.

Or is it possible if i will make import export ?
i tried this also

> https://github.com/MidwesternInteractive/laravel-db-sync

```
REMOTE_SYNC_URL=
REMOTE_SYNC_DB_NAME=
REMOTE_SYNC_SSH_USERNAME=
REMOTE_SYNC_SSH_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need any additional package for that.**

**Give separate credentials for two database (local and live) to `database.php` config file inside connections array.**

**Example:**

```
'my-local-db' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
],

'my-live-db' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_LIVE_HOST', '103.149.104.68'), // Put your live server database host here
  'port' => env('DB_LIVE_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_LIVE_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_LIVE_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_LIVE_PASSWORD', ''),
],
```

and set those in env veriables

Now, for example you want sync table from live to local

```
public function sync() {
     // Connect to live database
     $live_database = DB::connection('my-live-db');
     // Get table data from production
     foreach($live_database->table('table_name')->get() as $data){
        // Save data to staging database - default db connection
        DB::table('table_name')->insert((array) $data);
     }
     // Get table_2 data from production
     foreach($live_database->table('table_2_name')->get() as $data){
        // Save data to staging database - default db connection
        DB::table('table_2_name')->insert((array) $data);
     }
  }
```

Hope this will give you a basic concept about two database sync

Comment: what happened if i delete/update some data from local and then i will try to sync this way ?

Comment: please ... and why you put same host name?

Comment: this is just e example script. in your situation you should use different host name. for delete purpose i compared two table first. when the custom id numbers get mismatched then i can easily understand which id should be removed or which is new. another thing i check updated at column to check if the data is updated or not.

Comment: can you give real example for my-live-db

Comment: what will be `DB_LIVE_PORT` ?

Comment: all your live database credentials should be in hosting panel. generally its 3306

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (SQL: select * from `users`)

Comment: this database connection not established. make sure you placed your database credentials in your .env file

Comment: DB_LIVE_HOST=lazytechbd.com
DB_LIVE_PORT=3306
DB_LIVE_DATABASE=lazytec1_larapos
DB_LIVE_USERNAME=lazytec1_public
DB_LIVE_PASSWORD=mypass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181197/discussion-between-emtiaz-zahid-and-uzzal-hosen).

Comment: Hello Uzzal, I am also in similar situation. did you find the solution? please post it here!

Comment: i am also looking for solution ?

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad did you tried the solution I posted here?

Comment: yes i am still trying and looking for solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
'my-local-db' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
],

'my-live-db' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_LIVE_HOST', '103.149.104.68'), // Put your live server 
   database host here
  'port' => env('DB_LIVE_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_LIVE_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_LIVE_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_LIVE_PASSWORD', ''),
],

public function sync() {
     // Connect to live database
     $live_database = DB::connection('my-live-db');
     // Get table data from production
     foreach($live_database->table('table_name')->get() as $data){
        // Save data to staging database - default db connection
        DB::table('table_name')->insert((array) $data);
        // This query can do only one time for multiple time we have to do
        DB::table('table_name')->insertOrUpdate((array) $data); 
        // This query also update column only, if you do some changes in 
        //previous data it will not sync for that i dont know this query is 
        //correct or not but it worked.
        DB::table('table_name')->delete((array) $data);
        DB::table('table_name')->insertOrIgnore((array) $data);
     }
  }
```

Comment: please guide me to sync storage folder to different project if i am using offline project i have to show image also for that link will not for we have to sync storage also. If it is possible please guide me

Answer (score -1):

Creating an offline-online web application with Laravel that syncs data with a MySQL database when an internet connection is available can be a complex task. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution, but I can provide you with some guidance on how to approach this problem.

One way to achieve this is by implementing a queue-based system combined with Laravel's task scheduling and database synchronization. Here's a general outline of how you can approach this:

Queue System: Use Laravel's built-in queue system to manage synchronization tasks. When the application is online and an internet connection is available, enqueue tasks to synchronize data with the remote MySQL database. You can use Redis or other queue drivers supported by Laravel.

Task Scheduling: Set up scheduled tasks using Laravel's task scheduler (artisan schedule). These tasks can periodically check if there's an internet connection available and process the synchronization queue when the connection is detected. If there's no connection, the task can be scheduled to retry later.

Database Synchronization Logic: Implement the logic for database synchronization within the queue job. Laravel provides database tools like Eloquent to interact with your database. You'll need to write code to compare the local and remote databases and sync data accordingly.

Offline Mode: When the application is offline, you can still allow users to interact with the data locally. Use a local SQLite database or another storage mechanism to store data while offline. When the internet connection is restored, sync the local data with the remote MySQL database.

User-Initiated Sync: Implement a button or option that allows users to manually trigger data synchronization when they have an internet connection. This can be a fallback mechanism in case automatic synchronization encounters issues.

Handling Failures: Be prepared to handle synchronization failures gracefully. If a synchronization job fails, log the error and attempt to retry it later based on your scheduling logic.

Regarding the package you mentioned (laravel-db-sync), it appears to be a tool for database migrations rather than synchronization between local and remote databases. You may need to build your custom synchronization solution as described above.

Keep in mind that building a robust offline-online synchronization system can be complex, and you'll need to consider data conflicts, data consistency, and error handling in your implementation. It's essential to thoroughly test your solution in various scenarios to ensure it works reliably.

I hope this above guideline will help.

Regards,
Imran

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541