# Laravel sync offline database to online

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, synchronization

I want to sync my local database to online database when i click on a button in blade page. I looked online for the solution but did not found anything that worked for me.

I have updated my database .php file I have added local and server database connection credentials.
I have found a solution but that is not completed.

[solution that i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621082/laravel-sync-localhost-mysql-database-to-hosting-server)

*database.php*

```
 'local' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('LOCAL_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('LOCAL_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('LOCAL_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('LOCAL_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('LOCAL_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('LOCAL_DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'server' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('SERVER_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('SERVER_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('SERVER_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('SERVER_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('SERVER_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('SERVER_DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

**controller code**

```
 // Connect to local database
        return  $local_database = DB::connection('local-db')->table('table_name');
        // Get table data from production
        foreach ($local_database->table('table_name')->get() as $data) {
            // Save data to staging database - default db connection
            DB::table('table_name')->insert((array) $data);
            // This query can do only one time for multiple time we have to do
            DB::table('table_name')->insertOrUpdate((array) $data);
            // This query also update column only, if you do some changes in 
            //previous data it will not sync for that i dont know this query is 
            //correct or not but it worked.
            DB::table('table_name')->delete((array) $data);
            DB::table('table_name')->insertOrIgnore((array) $data);
        }
```

**env**

```
SERVER_DB_CONNECTION=server
SERVER_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
SERVER_DB_PORT=3306
SERVER_DB_DATABASE=sync_db
SERVER_DB_USERNAME=root
SERVER_DB_PASSWORD=

LOCAL_DB_CONNECTION=local
LOCAL_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
LOCAL_DB_PORT=3306
LOCAL_DB_DATABASE=sync_db
LOCAL_DB_USERNAME=root
LOCAL_DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Are you sure *local database to online database*?

Comment: Yes sir. and the tables too.

Comment: Have you tried doing anything like e.g. invoking mysqldump locally via a shell command and dumping the output in a script file that you can run on the remote database?

Comment: Make sure your server configuration on .env is correct, as far as I see, I dont think SERVER_DB_HOST should be 127.0.0.1 as it is localhost.

Comment: Yes sir. but I still not able to connect with my localdatabase. I get this error ```Database connection [local-db] not configured.```

Comment: I dont see any "local-db" in your configuration. Also, please update your question with the code showing what you have done for other people to check.